# My SQL loop takes to long to complete. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I am trying to de-duplicate a set of data based on certain columns. That is it isn't as easy as just `SELECT DISTINCT`.

I want to select from my set all rows where a column is unique. I have sorted my set in a way that I just want the loop to grab the first occurrence of the "proxy" key column. I'm saying proxy as it isn't the actual primary key of the table.

I'm using a while loop and using a counter variable based on the count of rows in a temp table. I delete each row from my temp table after processing so this should reduce the base table by the one record which was processed and any duplicate rows.

Although my code works it is seems 'cowboyish' and would like your opinion on how to do it 'cleaner' thanks

Here is my code:

```
declare @cnt int

set @cnt = (select COUNT(*) from #temp)

while @cnt > 0
begin       
    select top 1 * into #temp2 from #temp

    insert into #temp3 (Member_ID, email, meeting_status,member_type,firstname,lastname,address1, Match_Method, Match_Score)
        select #temp2.* 
        from #temp2
        left outer join #temp3 on #temp2.Member_ID = #temp3.Member_ID
        where #temp3.Member_ID is null

    delete #temp 
    from #temp
    inner join #temp2 on #temp.Member_ID = #temp2.Member_ID

    drop table #temp2

    set @cnt = (select COUNT(*) from #temp)
end
```

Comment: "I have sorted my set in a way...". No, no you haven't. Any ordering that you may have used at any point in the past is no longer relevant, unless you have stored that ordering information in one or more columns. Specifically, `select top 1 * into #temp2 from #temp` is free to select **any** row from `#temp`. So if the "first"ness of a row was important, there's something still missing from your question and the answers. But most of the answers are a good start. Your first instinct in SQL should always be "how do I process the entire *set*?", rather than row-by-row.

Comment: And where I said "stored that ordering information in one or more columns", I should also have said "and use those columns in an `ORDER BY` clause during any retrieval operation where this ordering matters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1:**

Use below code:

```
WITH uniqueRecords AS(
    SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.Member_ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNum
    FROM #Temp AS T
)
INSERT INTO #temp3(Member_ID, email, meeting_status,member_type,firstname,lastname,address1, Match_Method, Match_Score)
SELECT U.Member_ID, U.email, U.meeting_status,U.member_type,U.firstname,U.lastname,U.address1, U.Match_Method, U.Match_Score
FROM uniqueRecords AS U
LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp3 T3 on U.Member_ID = T3.Member_ID
WHERE U.RowNum=1
AND T3.Member_ID is null;
```

**OPTION 2:**

i) create UNIQUE INDEX on #temp3 ON Member_ID column WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_temp3 ON #temp3 (Member_ID) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON);
```

ii) insert result from `left join of #temp and #temp3`. duplicates will be ignored by `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option

```
INSERT INTO #temp3(Member_ID, email, meeting_status,member_type,firstname,lastname,address1, Match_Method, Match_Score)
SELECT T.Member_ID, T.email, T.meeting_status,T.member_type,T.firstname,T.lastname,T.address1, T.Match_Method, T.Match_Score
FROM #temp AS T
LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp3 T3 on T.Member_ID = T3.Member_ID
WHERE T3.Member_ID is null;
```

Comment: in your query if I comment out the INERT INTO and just select.. it selects exactly the amount of rows my code selects but does it in about 18 mins less  :). the insert is throwing an error though.. so I just changed the U.* to all fields except the RowNum thingy..

Comment: @Craigoh1 Glad that it helped. I have edited the ans. thanks for pointing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to insert rows from `#temp` into `#temp3`, but you want to make sure that only one row from the same `Member_ID` gets inserted. In that case, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and filter for `ROW_NUMBER = 1` to make sure that only one row from duplicate `Member_ID`s will be inserted. Then add a `NOT EXISTS` filter to avoid inserting already existing rows:

```
INSERT INTO #temp3 (Member_ID, email, meeting_status, member_type, firstname, lastname, address1, Match_Method, Match_Score)
    SELECT
        Member_ID,
        email,
        meeting_status,
        member_type,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        address1,
        Match_Method,
        Match_Score
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Member_ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM #temp
    ) t
    WHERE
        t.Rn = 1
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM #temp3 t3
            WHERE t3.Member_ID = t.MEMBER_ID
        )
```

Comment: does the NOT EXISTS check again after each INSERT?

Comment: @Craigoh1 No, it evaluates the `SELECT` as a whole. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I tried but it still inserted the duplicates hence why im using the loop and delete.

Comment: can you explain what the row_number() over partition bit please.. I have never seen this before. thanks

Comment: @Craigoh1 [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition. So filtering for `ROW_NUMBER = 1` will return only one row for each partition.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not have to re-count your table every time in a loop. You can simply decrement `@cnt`.
2. You should not re-create `#temp2` every time in the loop. You can re-use it
3. You do not have to use `#temp2` at all. You can just use `select top 1 * from #temp` instead
4. You do not have to use loop at all, just use following script instead:

   ```
   insert into #temp3(Member_ID, email, meeting_status, member_type, firstname, lastname, address1, Match_Method, Match_Score)
       select * 
       from #temp
       where Member_ID not in (select Member_ID from #temp3)
   ```

Comment: Thanks Slava for your comments. However if "A" exists twice in #temp it will still insert into #temp3 twice because at the time of producing the 'set', "A" didn't exist in #temp3 hence why I'm using a loop to check every row before inserting. Or am I just completely lost... does the NOT IN recheck #temp3 after every insert??

Comment: If your #temp table has complete duplicates then you can add "DISTINCT". If duplicates are not complete, you have to define the rule: which record will be inserted and which won't.